# How does resConfigs work in android (gradle)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build

Lack of proper documentation on gradle method `resConfigs` made me ask this question.

### Official documentation:

- In [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources) example, google gives a specific example of how to use it
  with Languages.
- In [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#reduce_resources) example, google mixed Languages and
  Drawables
- I was unable to find any *javadoc* like gradle doc for the same

---

### My (mostly wrong) understanding:

If I specify something in front of `resConfigs`, only that gets included in the final build, everything else does not get bundled into the apk.

---

### Android app setup

The test app has

- Multiple languages (values-en , values-fr, ...)
- Multiple drawable folders (drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, ...)
- Multiple android versions (values-v21 , values-v7, ...)
- Multiple smallest widths(sw800, sw1000, ...)
- Multiple orientations (port,land)
- etc

---

### My Test Observations

Note: I used android studios' apk analyzer to deduce the following results. before every test, full clean, rebuild, and prod build was generated with proguard(shrink) enabled.

---

**Test 1:**
I specified only languages `resConfigs="en", "fr"`

**Result 1:**
In the apk,

- all languages vanished except en and fr
- all other resources were present (drawables, dimens, sw, orientation ...)

---

**Test 2:**
I specified only drawables `resConfigs="xxhdpi"`

**Result 2:**
In the apk,

- all languages were present
- all other resources were present (dimens, sw, orientation ...)
- all drawables vanished except xxhdpi. (all other drawable folders were present, but had 0 byte files)

---

**Test 3:**
I specified languages and drawable `resConfigs="en","fr","xxhdpi"`

**Result 3:**
In the apk,

- all languages vanished except en and fr
- all other resources were present (dimens, sw, orientation ...)
- all drawables vanished except xxhdpi.

---

### Questions:

1. When I only specify languages `resConfigs="en", "fr"`, why are other resources getting bundled into the apk (for eg: drawables)
2. Similary, when I only specify  `resConfigs="xxhdpi"` , why languages and other resources get bundled
3. In case of gradle is using some intelligence to figure out what to exclude and what not to exclude, does there exist a list of group of resources which fall under same category, is there any documentation on it?
   For eg

   - Language is a group, if gradle finds at least one language tag, it excludes all other languages. otherwise, includes all languages?
   - Drawable is a group, if gradle finds at least one drawable tag, it excludes all other drawables. otherwise, includes all drawables?

---

### Related Questions:

1. `resConfigs` only worked for me on app level gradle only. When I tried to use it on a dependent module, it ignored it completely. How to make it work on a dependent module. (I was trying to integrate [firebaseUI for auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth))
2. is `resConfigs` in early stages of development, or is it meant only for development purposes, and not to be used in prod setups?

Comment: The `resConfigs` is defined in the Android plugin for gradle.  
You can find the doc API [available here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) but nothing special. It seems to work with the [qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here are a few things to keep in mind

- resConfigs works with resource qualifiers groups
- resource qualifiers are grouped in different buckets like language , dpi , platform version etc .

When you provide a resource qualifier to resConfigs then all other resources for qualifiers in that bucket will be removed. Resources in other buckets are not affected .

Please refer to the following link for all the available grouping/buckets .
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

hope this makes sense.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. But resConfig doesn't work if you specific it in a dependent module . Even firebase auth ui gihub library tells us to put resConfigs in app level build folder. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth